# How did mysql workbench get my old database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mysql-workbench, workbench

I created database using mysql from phpmyadmin for some practice purposes. Now I've just downloaded and set up mysql workbench and right after I saw my old database which I created in phpmyadmin and that makes me wonder how did workbench get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both **phpMyAdmin** and **MySQL Workbench** are administration/client tools. It is used to connect MySQL Service running on your machine / remote machine called server. (usually on port 3306).

When you create databases or store data which is stored under a folder represented as [datadir](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datadir) which is owned by the MySQL service.

> how did workbench get it?

Database is managed by MySQL Service, like a phpMyAdmin, Workbench also another client, connecting to same MySQL Service.

Similarly, you can use any other [MySQL Client](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20client%20tools&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN939IN939&oq=mysql%20client%20tools&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i22i30l5.3818j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to connect with the same MySQL service running on your machine.

Additionally, you can refer [my blog](https://www.rathishkumar.com/2016/04/understanding-mysql-architecture.html) to understand more about MySQL Architecture.